# best way to extract object from an activerecord relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What would be the best way to iterate through an active relation. Let's say I have an active relation object returned. I want to break it down into the corresponding category of their parent. I have 12 categories for products, and I'm building 12 dropdowns!

Product belongs to category
Product has many favorites
User    has_many :products, through: :favorites

```
Favorite.includes(:product).where('user_id = ?', current_user.id).each do |favorite|
...?...
end
```

Comment: is your question still open?

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like:

```
grouped_favorites = Favorite.includes(:product => :category)
                            .where('user_id = ?', current_user.id)
                            .group_by {|favorite| favorite.product.category }

grouped_favorites.each do |category, favorites|
   favorites.each do |favorite|
     ...?...
   end
end
```